# Putting an outline on a mask in a SVG

Tags: html, svg, masking

Is it possible to put an outline or something on a mask so that you can actually see where the mask is? I have an element that I'm trying to mask, but I can't actually see if lining up to where it should.

What I'm trying to do is use the endScreen ID as a mask and using the startOrder ID for the object being masked. Right not it's masking it, but not correctly and it would be nice to visibly be able to see the mask where it is in the design.

```
<svg id="demo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 337.32 386.57">
            <style>
                .st0 {
                    fill: #fff
                }

                .st5 {
                    fill: #c32034
                }
            </style>

            <defs>
                <mask id="button-mask" width="1" height="1">
                     <path d="M51.24 372.52V52.27c0-15.4 12.6-28 28-28h180.79c15.4 0 28 12.6 28 28v320.25" fill="white" />
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <path id="endScreen" class="st0" d="M51.24 372.52V52.27c0-15.4 12.6-28 28-28h180.79c15.4 0 28 12.6 28 28v320.25" />
            <circle id="startScreen" class="st0" cx="167.67" cy="199.37" r="91" />
            <path id="base" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M6 374.88h326.27" />
            <path id="phoneOutline" d="M302.12 372.43V55.31c0-25.15-21.05-45.73-46.78-45.73H82.26c-25.73 0-46.78 20.58-46.78 45.73v317.13" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="7.358" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
            <circle id="speakerSmall" cx="204.78" cy="43.04" r="4.4" fill="#c1a88b" />
            <path id="speakerLarge" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="9" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M132.04 43.23h59.45" />
            <path id="startOrder" class="st5" d="M236.62 337.2H99.44c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-20.48c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h137.17c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v20.48c.01 6.6-5.39 12-11.99 12z" mask="url(#button-mask)" />
            <path id="star" class="st5" d="M168.66 91.97l4.94 10.01 11.04 1.6-7.99 7.79 1.89 11.01-9.88-5.2-9.89 5.2 1.89-11.01-7.99-7.79 11.05-1.6z" />
            <circle id="endOrder" cx="165.72" cy="313.53" r="36.5" fill="#89bd40" />
            <path id="check" fill="none" stroke="#fdfeff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M147.32 255.76l12.88 11.5 23.93-23.46" />
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the path you want to use for the mask first as a template by itself, without any presentation attribute, and then reference it twice: first, inside the mask with `fill="white"`, and then again with `fill="none" stroke="blue"` on top off your grafic.

You'll note your path isn't closed, but obviously a fill will create an implicit close between the endpoints, which the stroke doesn't show. An easy solution that changes effectively nothing for your mask is to add a `z` command at the end of the path definition.

```css
.st0 {
    fill: #fff
}

.st5 {
    fill: #c32034
}
```

```html
<svg id="demo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 337.32 386.57">
    <defs>
        <path id="shape" d="M51.24 372.52V52.27c0-15.4 12.6-28 28-28h180.79c15.4 0 28 12.6 28 28v320.25" fill="white" />
        <mask id="button-mask" width="1" height="1">
             <use href="#shape" fill="white" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <path id="endScreen" class="st0" d="M51.24 372.52V52.27c0-15.4 12.6-28 28-28h180.79c15.4 0 28 12.6 28 28v320.25" />
    <circle id="startScreen" class="st0" cx="167.67" cy="199.37" r="91" />
    <path id="base" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M6 374.88h326.27" />
    <path id="phoneOutline" d="M302.12 372.43V55.31c0-25.15-21.05-45.73-46.78-45.73H82.26c-25.73 0-46.78 20.58-46.78 45.73v317.13" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="7.358" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    <circle id="speakerSmall" cx="204.78" cy="43.04" r="4.4" fill="#c1a88b" />
    <path id="speakerLarge" fill="none" stroke="#c1a88b" stroke-width="9" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M132.04 43.23h59.45" />
    <path id="startOrder" class="st5" d="M236.62 337.2H99.44c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-20.48c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h137.17c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v20.48c.01 6.6-5.39 12-11.99 12z" mask="url(#button-mask)" />
    <path id="star" class="st5" d="M168.66 91.97l4.94 10.01 11.04 1.6-7.99 7.79 1.89 11.01-9.88-5.2-9.89 5.2 1.89-11.01-7.99-7.79 11.05-1.6z" />
    <circle id="endOrder" cx="165.72" cy="313.53" r="36.5" fill="#89bd40" />
    <path id="check" fill="none" stroke="#fdfeff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M147.32 255.76l12.88 11.5 23.93-23.46" />
    <use href="#shape" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
</svg>
```

It might be worth noting that this is a solution only fitting for your specific situation. If the mask had a stroke defined, another stroke *around* that one cannot be shown like that. Effectively, the technique is more fit for a clip-path (that is pure form) than a mask (which is a arbitrary grafical structure).